# Getting PHP 500 internal error on multipart function

Tags: swift, multipart

I am hitting an API which is like chat messages in which we can send attachment as image or pdf and normal text . This was working good when I upload the app on App Store but when I Checked it yesterday, the API is now throwing me an error on sending simple text (No attachments) . it is showing me "500 Internal Server Error"

API Function :-

```
    if arraymultipartObject.count > 0
    {
        for obj in arraymultipartObject{
            if obj.image != nil {

                let imagene = obj.image
                let resizedImage = imagene?.compressImage()
                profileImageData  = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(resizedImage!,1.0)
                SavedImgDataArr.addObjects(from: [profileImageData!])
                SavedPDFDataArr.removeAllObjects()
            }
            else {
                let pdf = obj.urlpdf
                print(pdf)

                sendpdfData = try! Data(contentsOf: URL(string: pdf!)!)//pdf?.data(using: .utf8)
                // sendpdfData   = NSData(data: pdfData) //NSData(data: UIImageJPEGRepresentation((resizedImage!), 1)!)
                SavedPDFDataArr.addObjects(from: [sendpdfData!])
                SavedImgDataArr.removeAllObjects()
            }

        }
    }
    print(selectedFileName)
    var messagetext = (textfiledMessage.text?.trimmingCharacters(in: .newlines))!
    if messagetext == "Type a message"
    {
        messagetext = ""
    }
    let dictionary = ["uuid":UUid,"device_id":devicetoken,"school_id":LoginUserInfo.sharedInstance.schoolId!, "to": toStr,"title": titleStr, "description": messagetext,"class_id": classId ,"section_id":SectionId,"particulars":particulars,"teacher_ids":teacherIDS, "student_ids":StudentIDs,"notice_type":noticeType]
      print(dictionary)
    let encoder = JSONEncoder()
    if let jsonData = try? encoder.encode(dictionary) {
        if let jsonString = String(data: jsonData, encoding: .utf8) {
            //  print(jsonString)
            let cipher:String = CryptoHelper.encrypt(input:jsonString)!;
             let NewEncryption = ["data":cipher]as [String:String]
           // let NewEncryption = "data=\(cipher)"
            print(NewEncryption)
            let hmac_md5 = cipher.hmac(algorithm: .sha512, key: kHMACKey)
             print("hmac",hmac_md5)
            UserDefaults.standard.set(hmac_md5, forKey: Headerkey)
             let urlString = BaseURl + KSCreateMessage
            Singleton.sharedInstance.postApiMethodWithMultipleImage(parms: NewEncryption, url: urlString, ImgArr: SavedImgDataArr, pdfArr: SavedPDFDataArr, selectedFileExtension: selectedFileName, onCompilation:
                { (result) in
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    ReusableClass.sharedInstance.hideActivityIndicator()
                }
                if result != nil
                {
                    do {
                        let jsonData = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: result)
                        if let json = String(data: jsonData, encoding: .utf8) {
                            let Dict = function.convertToDictionary(text: json)! as NSDictionary
                            guard let data = Dict[KData] as? String
                                else
                            {
                                return
                            }

                            self.baseDict = data

                        }
                    }
                    catch {
                    }
                    guard  let output = CryptoHelper.decrypt(input:self.baseDict)
                        else
                    {
                        return
                    }
                    print(output)
                    let mainDict = function.convertToDictionary(text: output)! as NSDictionary
                    let status = mainDict[KStatus]  as! NSInteger
                    if(status == 1)
                    {.......}
```

Singleton Class Functions to hit API:-

```
   //MARK update image with single image
    func postApiMethodWithMultipleImage(parms: [String:String], url: String, ImgArr: NSMutableArray?, pdfArr:NSMutableArray?,selectedFileExtension:String?, onCompilation: (@escaping ImgPostCompletionHandler)){

        let myUrl = NSURL(string: url);
        ReusableClass.sharedInstance.showActivityIndicator()
        let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url:myUrl! as URL);
        request.httpMethod = "POST";

        let boundary = generateBoundaryString()
        request.setValue("multipart/form-data; boundary=\(boundary)", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
      //  request.setValue("application/x-www-form-urlencoded", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
        if UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: "header") != nil {
            request.addValue(UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: "header") as! String, forHTTPHeaderField:"HMAC" )
            print(UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: "header") as! String)
        }

        if selectedFileExtension == "pdf" {

                    request.httpBody = (createBodyWithParameterPDFArray(parameters: parms,
                                                                       filePathKey: "FileName",
                                                                       pdfKeyArr: pdfArr,
                                                                       boundary: boundary)) as Data

        }
        else if selectedFileExtension == "image" //|| selectedFileExtension == ""
        {

            request.httpBody = (createBodyWithParameter(parameters: parms,
                                                        filePathKey: "FileName",
                                                        profile_imageKey: ImgArr,
                                                        boundary: boundary)) as Data

        }else { //here I'm this function things go wrong
            request.httpBody = (createBodyWithParameterTEST(parameters: parms,
                                                        filePathKey: "FileName",
                                                        profile_imageKey: ImgArr,
                                                        boundary: boundary)) as Data
        }

        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest) {
            data, response, error in
            ReusableClass.sharedInstance.hideActivityIndicator()
            if error != nil {
                print("error=\(error)")
                var errorInfo = NSDictionary()
                errorInfo = ["result" : "Failure", "message" : error?.localizedDescription as Any]
                onCompilation(errorInfo)

                return
            }

            // You can print out response object
            print("******* response = \(response)")

            // Print out reponse body
            //let responseString = NSString(data: data!, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)
            let responseString = NSString(data: data!, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)
            print("****** response data = \(responseString!)")

            do {
                let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: []) as? NSDictionary

                print(json!)
                onCompilation(json!)

            }catch
            {
                print(error)
            }
        }
        task.resume()

    }
```

PDf Function :-

```
//pdf array
func createBodyWithParameterPDFArray(parameters: [String: String]?, filePathKey: String?, pdfKeyArr: NSMutableArray?,boundary: String) -> NSData {
    let body = NSMutableData();

    if parameters != nil
    {
        for (key, value) in parameters!
        {
            body.appendString(string: "--\(boundary)\r\n")
            body.appendString(string: "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"\(key)\"\r\n\r\n")
            body.appendString(string: "\(value)\r\n")
        }
    }
    let mimetype = "application/pdf"
    let filename = String(Int(Date().timeIntervalSince1970)) +  "doc.pdf"
    print("file name",filename)
    //1
    if(pdfKeyArr != nil){
        for i in  pdfKeyArr!{
            body.appendString(string: "--\(boundary)\r\n")
            body.appendString(string: "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"\("attachments[]")\"; filename=\"\(filename)\"\r\n")
            body.appendString(string: "Content-Type: \(mimetype)\r\n\r\n")

            if (pdfKeyArr != nil) {
                body.append(i as! Data)
            }
            body.appendString(string: "\r\n")
            body.appendString(string: "--\(boundary)--\r\n")
        }
    }
    return body
}
```

Image Multipart Function:-

```
func createBodyWithParameter(parameters: [String: String]?, filePathKey: String?, profile_imageKey: NSMutableArray?,boundary: String) -> NSData {
    let body = NSMutableData();

    if parameters != nil
    {
        for (key, value) in parameters!
        {
            body.appendString(string: "--\(boundary)\r\n")
            body.appendString(string: "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"\(key)\"\r\n\r\n")
            body.appendString(string: "\(value)\r\n")
        }
    }
    let mimetype = "image/jpg"
    let filename = String(Int(Date().timeIntervalSince1970)) +  "Img.jpg"
    print("file name",filename)
    //1
    if(profile_imageKey != nil){
        for i in  profile_imageKey!{
            body.appendString(string: "--\(boundary)\r\n")
            body.appendString(string: "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"\("attachments[]")\"; filename=\"\(filename)\"\r\n")
            body.appendString(string: "Content-Type: \(mimetype)\r\n\r\n")

            if (profile_imageKey != nil) {
                body.append(i as! Data)
            }
            body.appendString(string: "\r\n")
            body.appendString(string: "--\(boundary)--\r\n")
        }
    }
    return body
}
```

Simple text function(Multipart) :-

```
  //test empty data and simple String
    func createBodyWithParameterTEST(parameters: [String: String]?, filePathKey: String?, profile_imageKey: NSMutableArray?,boundary: String) -> NSData {


        let body = NSMutableData();

        if parameters != nil
        {
            for (key, value) in parameters!
            {
                body.appendString(string: "--\(boundary)\r\n")
                body.appendString(string: "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"\(key)\"\r\n\r\n")
                body.appendString(string: "\(value)\r\n")

            }
        }
        let mimetype = "image/jpg"
        let filename = String(Int(Date().timeIntervalSince1970)) +  "Img.jpg"
        print("file name",filename)
        //1
        if(profile_imageKey != nil){
            for i in  profile_imageKey!{
                body.appendString(string: "--\(boundary)\r\n")
                body.appendString(string: "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"\("attachments[]")\"; filename=\"\(filename)\"\r\n")
                body.appendString(string: "Content-Type: \(mimetype)\r\n\r\n")

                if (profile_imageKey != nil) {
                    body.append(i as! Data)
                }
                body.appendString(string: "\r\n")
                body.appendString(string: "--\(boundary)--\r\n")
            }
        }
        return body
    }
```

This is the error :-

```
******* response = Optional(<NSHTTPURLResponse: 0x2800c4f20> { URL: https://demo.com/admin/index.php/api/chat/create_message } { Status Code: 500, Headers {
    "Content-Length" =     (
        666
    );
    "Content-Type" =     (
        "text/html; charset=iso-8859-1"
    );
    Date =     (
        "Tue, 23 Jul 2019 11:27:56 GMT"
    );
    Server =     (
        Apache
    );
} })
****** response data = <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>500 Internal Server Error</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Internal Server Error</h1>
<p>The server encountered an internal error or
misconfiguration and was unable to complete
your request.</p>
<p>Please contact the server administrator at 
 webmaster@kakshase.com to inform them of the time this error occurred,
 and the actions you performed just before this error.</p>
<p>More information about this error may be available
in the server error log.</p>
<p>Additionally, a 500 Internal Server Error
error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.</p>
</body></html>
```

Comment: You should look at your error logs on your server, 500 is a server side error

Comment: Please Check now I have updated my question, it is working god in postman and android and also was working god in iOS too but don't know when I migrated from Xcode 10.1 to Xcode 10.2 it somehow not working

Comment: It's still a server-side error

Comment: maybe while you are migrating you are forgetting your info.plist ? App Transport Security Settings -> Allow Arbitrary Loads -> YES

Comment: it is already added there in plist

Comment: I doubt this is the issue, but the `body.appendString(string: "--\(boundary)--\r\n”)` in the wrong place in those three routines. It should be after the `for` loop, not inside it.

Comment: In terms of diagnosing what the issue is, if you have a working postman request, I’d suggest watching both via [Charles](https://charlesproxy.com) or [WireShark](https://wireshark.org) and identify how they differ.

Comment: Unrelated, but I’d replace those `NSMutableData`, `NSMutableURLRequest`, `NSString`, and `NSURL` with `Data`, `Request`, `String`, and `URL`, respectively. Also lose those semicolons.

Comment: Also, looking at `let filename = String(Int(Date().timeIntervalSince1970)) +  "doc.pdf"`, makes it look like you were trying to create unique filenames, but obviously if you were adding more than one file (and potentially, even if you weren’t), the file names won’t be unique. So, if your web service needs unique filenames, this won’t work. And if your web service doesn’t require unique filenames, I’d just get rid of this confusing code.

Comment: The `"...; name=\"\("attachments[]")\"; ..."` is strange. Why use string interpolation with a string literal? Why not `"...; name=\"attachments[]\"; ..."`? And I’m not sure about the `[]`...

Comment: "attachments[]" is the key backend devs assigned it like this. I will try your all suggestion and then give feedback to it

Comment: IIRC, if you supply `attachments`, it automatically appears as an array on the server, so you might try removing the `[]`. But, I confess, I haven’t tested this recently and my memory may be incorrect on this score. I still think, though, that comparing your working postman request vs code-generated via Charles or Wireshark is going to be the best way to unambiguously confirm what’s going down the wire and compare and contrast.

Comment: @Rob none worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are sending only String instead of data in the multipart function you must complete the multipart function with `body.appendString(string: "--\(boundary)--\r\n")` when you are checking for parameter key values in for loop.

Here is the Fix:-

```
  //test empty data and simple String
    func createBodyWithParameterTEST(parameters: [String: String]?, filePathKey: String?, profile_imageKey: NSMutableArray?,boundary: String) -> NSData {


        let body = NSMutableData();

        if parameters != nil
        {
            for (key, value) in parameters!
            {
                body.appendString(string: "--\(boundary)\r\n")
                body.appendString(string: "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"\(key)\"\r\n\r\n")
                body.appendString(string: "\(value)\r\n")
                body.appendString(string: "--\(boundary)--\r\n") //Call Boundary here also so that if there is not data and only string you are sending this will complete the multipart funtion here 
            }
        }
        let mimetype = "image/jpg"
        let filename = String(Int(Date().timeIntervalSince1970)) +  "Img.jpg"
        print("file name",filename)
        //1
        if(profile_imageKey != nil){
            for i in  profile_imageKey!{
                body.appendString(string: "--\(boundary)\r\n")
                body.appendString(string: "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"\("attachments[]")\"; filename=\"\(filename)\"\r\n")
                body.appendString(string: "Content-Type: \(mimetype)\r\n\r\n")

                if (profile_imageKey != nil) {
                    body.append(i as! Data)
                }
                body.appendString(string: "\r\n")
                body.appendString(string: "--\(boundary)--\r\n")
            }
        }
        return body
    }
```